# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{a_{n}} \right)^{a_{n}}=e$ if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{n}=\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

What would be the nicest proof of the following theorem:

> If $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = \infty$, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{a_{n}} \right) ^ {a_{n} } = e$.
>
> If $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_{n} = 0$, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + b_{n} \right) ^ {\frac {1} {b_{n}} } = e$.

I somehow failed to find a proof here on the website and in the literature.

Comment: Use the fact $(1+1/n)^n$ is monotone.

Comment: Are the $a_n$ and $b_n$ integers or real numbers?

Comment: @Arthur If they were integers, the theorem would follow from the fact that the limit of any subsequence is in fact the limit of the whole sequence, I think. But they are not necessarily integers.

Comment: "What would be the nicest proof", asked 35 minutes ago ... answer already accepted. Hmmm ... I am sure there will be more people coming with various interesting proofs, but ... leave the question open for at least a week before choosing the "nicest" ;)

Comment: @rtybase Haha, I should have added I meant nicest in terms of being elementary, then RRL's answer is hard to beat. :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{\lfloor a_n \rfloor+1} \right)^{\lfloor a_n \rfloor} \leqslant \left(1 + \frac{1}{a_n} \right)^{a_n} \leqslant \left(1 + \frac{1}{\lfloor a_n \rfloor} \right)^{\lfloor a_n \rfloor+1}, $$

and

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^n, \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1} \to e$$

Comment: That's infact the same way you follow to demonstrate the basic limits, I don't really see any big insight in this.

Comment: Just a way to apply the squeeze theorem when $a_n$ is not an integer, given the limit result for $(1 + 1/n)^n$ where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @RRL Thank you, a brilliant answer; somehow making $a_{n}$'s integers was what I was looking for (but didn't come up with a way to do this).

Comment: @Theta: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Given that $\lim_{n\to\infty }b_n =  \lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{1}{a_{n}}=0$
we have,

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{a_{n}} \right) ^ {a_{n} } = \lim_{n \to\infty} \exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{a_{n}} \right)}{\frac1{a_{n}}} \right)=  \lim_{h \to0} \exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1 +h \right)}{h} \right)=e$$

similarly

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(1 +b_n \right) ^ { \frac{1}{b_{n}}} = \lim_{n \to\infty} \exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1 + b_n\right)}{b_n} \right)=  \lim_{h \to0} \exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1 +h \right)}{h} \right)=e$$

Answer (score 2):

**Let's do the 1st one ...**

[One of the logarithmic inequalities says](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents): $$\frac{x}{1+x} < \ln (1 + x) < x, \forall x > -1$$

Because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n \rightarrow \infty$, then $a_n > 0$ and $\frac{1}{a_n} > 0$ from some $n$ onwards. So
$$0<\frac{1}{a_n+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{a_n}}{1+\frac{1}{a_n}} < \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{a_n}\right) < \frac{1}{a_n}$$
Given $e^x$ is ascending:
$$1<e^{\frac{1}{a_n+1}} <  1 + \frac{1}{a_n} < e^{\frac{1}{a_n}}$$
and from some $n$ onwards
$$e^{\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}} <  \left(1 + \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n} < e$$
Squeeze theorem finishes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

For $|t|<1$, note that
$t-{1 \over 2} t^2 \le \log(1+t) \le t$ and so
$|\log(1+t)-t| \le {1 \over 2} t^2$.

Hence for $|x|>1$ we have
$|\log(1+{1 \over x})-{1 \over x}| \le {1 \over 2} ({1\over x})^2$ and
so
$|x\log(1+{1 \over x})-1| \le {1 \over 2} {1\over |x|}$.

Hence $\lim_{x \to \infty} x\log(1+{1 \over x}) =\lim_{x \to \infty} \log(1+{1 \over x})^x =  1$ from which it
follows that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+{1 \over x})^x = e$.

Answer (score 1):

One does L'Hospital to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}=e$, then one does sequential characterisation of limit. Similar reasoning applied to $b_{n}\rightarrow 0$ case.

Comment: As sequences are introduced earlier in a calculus course, supposse I don't have suffient knowledge on L'Hospital and functions in general, could you suggest a solution?

Comment: @RRL has provided a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

For any $a_n$ exists $x\in \mathbb N$ such that $x\le a_n\le x+1$ and

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x +1} \right)^{x} \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{a_n} \right)^{a_n} \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x+1}$$

and

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x +1} \right)^{x} =\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{x +1} \right)^{x+1}}{1 + \frac{1}{x +1} } \to \frac e 1=e$$

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x+1}=\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x}\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)\to e \cdot 1=e$$

then we can conclude by squeeze theorem.

Comment: No, it's not a direct consequence by a simple change of variables. No one said anything about the $a_n$ being integers.

Comment: @Arthur: If you read this answer carefully, he never required $n$ to be an integer.

Comment: I'm referring to the function-sequence criteria.

Comment: When we read it carefully, the limits are not even right.

Comment: @Arthur You can also take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554910/proving-the-limit-of-a-function-of-a-sequence-is-equal-to-the-function-of-the-li

Comment: @gimusi Thank you for your answer but if I wanted one that requires only the knowledge a student has the moment sequences are introduced on his lectures?

Comment: @Theta It can be easily shown also for sequence following the same step as for the basic limits! It doesn't change so much what is going on. Regards.

Comment: Have you ever noticed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n)^{1/n}$ is not $e$? Actually, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n)^{1/n}=1$ because $n^{1/n}\leq(1+n)^{1/n}\leq(2n)^{1/n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.