# Limit of $((1+z_n)^{1/z_n})^{\log n}$ for sequence $z_n\to 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(z_n)$ be any sequence with $\lim_n z_n=0$.

Then, what is

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((1+z_n)^{1/z_n}\right)^{\log n}?
$$

By the linked question, I know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+z_n)^{1/z_n}=e.
$$

Nut how to handle the outer exponent $\log n$?

Comment: The limit can hardly be $1$ in general if it is $e$ in a special case, can it?

Comment: Oh, yes. That was stupid.

Comment: Our best hope to define $(1+z_n)^{1/z_n})$ is $(1+z_n)^{1/z_n}):=\exp(\frac1{z_n}\ln(1+ z_n))$ where fortunalety $1+\frac1{z_n}>0$ for almost all $n$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{a_{n}} \right)^{a_{n}}=e$ if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{n}=\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554111/prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-left1-frac1a-n-righta)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the exponent $\log n$ which makes it a different question, I guess.

Comment: @mathfemi given the time discrepancy between the original post and the update, and the fact that there are 3 closing votes already, I'd suggest closing this question and opening another one with the right content ... otherwise it may not attract the desired attention (with 3 closing votes)

Comment: okay! i agree. good idea

Comment: @mathfemi If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply note that **it is not an indeterminate form** thus

$$\left((1+z_n)^{1/z_n}\right)^{\log n}\to e^{+\infty}=+\infty$$

As an alternative note that

$$\left((1+z_n)^{1/z_n}\right)^{\log n}=e^{\log n \cdot \log \left((1+z_n)^{1/z_n}\right)}\to e^{+\infty\cdot 1}=+\infty$$

Comment: Sorry, but for me it is not clear why we can treat the limit in the exponent independent from the limit $e$.

Comment: its an algebraic rule for limit calculation, you can also derive it in other ways

Comment: @gimusi this question is a duplicate and the link I posted as a duplicate also contains an answer from you. Let's keep this site clean by avoiding replicating the answers and spotting duplicates ...

Comment: It is no duplicate since the exponent $\log n$ does not appear there.

Comment: @mathfemi then this question needs to be closed since it diverges from the original post ...