# Can I solve this limit like this? $\lim \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I think I can use L'Hopital's rule here but I did it differently:

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} = \\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}} = \ln(e) = 1$$

Is this correct? I thought this trick could only be used with constants.

Comment: That is a correct application of log properties and the limit definition of $e$. Which step specifically do you mean could only be used with constants?

Comment: @NinadMunshi When you have $p*\ln(x)$ is becomes $\ln(x^p)$ but I thought this could only be used when p is a constant. I decided to give it a try here and it worked so I was wondering if it was just chance or if it could be used with variables too.

Comment: Silence.Well done.perhaps mention $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: There is no stipulation that the property does not hold for variables. They both use letters, and in this case the distinction between constant and variable only exists in our minds. However I do want to applaud you for doing something many students are afraid to do without guidance: guessing the rule. It seems you were unsure whether or not something applied and you correctly deduced it had to be of the same form as something else you have seen before. This is a skill that will take you far in math.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks. To be honest, this stuff is no fun if you don't play around with things and experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I think if

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln \left(
\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{\sqrt{n}}
\right) = \ln \left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{\sqrt{n}}
\right)$$

is valid so the method is valid

Comment: You can swap a limit and a function, provided it is continuous.

Comment: if $f$ be continues and $lim(g(x)$  exists so$lim f(g(x))=f(lim(g(x))$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [the fact that](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1) 
$$\frac{x}{1+x}\leq \ln{(1+x)}\leq x, \forall x>-1$$
In this case
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq \ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \iff \\
\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}\leq \ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \iff \\
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}\leq \frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq 1 $$
and [squeeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Re the trick, here is the [general solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554111/prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-left1-frac1a-n-righta/), given $\ln{x}$ [is continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) at $e$.

Comment: That's useful, but not answering the actual question.

Comment: @ClementC. the last link does.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. So 10% of the answer, and the least apparent.