# Show $\log{a_n}\rightarrow\log{a}$ as ${n\rightarrow\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, proof-explanation

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{R}$ and assume $a_n>0$ and $a_n\rightarrow a>0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

The sequence $a_n$ clearly converges and I am inclined to think that if $a_n$ is convergent with the above statement being true, then

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\log(a_n)=\log(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n})}$ but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: $\log x$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554910/proving-the-limit-of-a-function-of-a-sequence-is-equal-to-the-function-of-the-li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result can come directly from the continuity of $\log$... But, just for using something different, Lagrange's theorem allows you to establish that
$$
|\log a_n - \log a| = \frac{1}{\xi_n}|a_n -a|, \quad \xi_n \in (a_n, a)
$$

From the previous equality, we get
$$
\lim |\log a_n -\log a| = \lim \frac{1}{\xi_n}|a_n-a| = \frac 1a \cdot 0=0,
$$

which in turn means that $\lim a_n =a$.