# $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if $\forall\{x_n\}:\ x_n\to x$, $\displaystyle\frac{f(x_n)-f(x)}{x_n-x} $ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\ (a,b)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ and $x\in(a,b)$. I want to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if for all $\{x_n\}\subset(a,b):\ x_n\to x$, we have
$$\frac{f(x_n)-f(x)}{x_n-x} $$
is a convergent sequence.

The forward direction is done easily by the definition. But I am having some confusion with the converse.

I am able to use the theorem that "$f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for all $\{x_n\}:\ x_n\to x,\ f(x_n)\to f(x)$".

But my impedent here is that though the limit $L$ of $\displaystyle \frac{f(x_n)-f(x)}{x_n-x} $ exists, I have no idea how to show that $L=f'(x)$, because I need this to be able to apply the above theorem.

What should I do ? Could anyone enlight me with some idea ? Thanks

Comment: I think you have nothing to prove since this is the definition of $f'(x)$.

Comment: @bayes2021 The definition usually doesn't use sequences this way. There is definitely something to prove here.

Comment: @Arthur may you explain more explicitly ?

Comment: @bayes2021: it's a possible definition of $f'$, but not the usual one.  PermQi can you tell us what definition of differentiability you have been given. If you have been told to use the theorem you quote, then I think you may have been misled. I'd expect to prove this from first principles using the definition of differentiability.

Comment: It may be that what you really need to do is to adapt the *proof* of the corresponding theorem for continuity, rather than to use that theorem itself.

Comment: @RobArthan the definition of differentiability at $x$ is there exists the limit $f'(x)=\lim_{y\to x}\displaystyle\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$, am I right ?

Comment: That's the standard definition. I suggest you try to show it's equivalent to the alternative formulation in terms of sequences converging to $x$ using the method of proof of the theorem you quote.

Comment: @RobArthan so I will do it by the proof of contradiction ?

Comment: I don't see any need to do a proof by contradiction. But I think you should follow the proof you have been given of the theorem about continuity that you mention.

Comment: You can apply the theorem to an appropriate function $g$ *provided* you know that for every sequence you get the same limit $L$. Can you first show that? Then define $g$ with $g(x)=L$ and apply that given result.

Comment: This is a particular case of a more general theorem about limits of functions. You can see eg. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554910/proving-the-limit-of-a-function-of-a-sequence-is-equal-to-the-function-of-the-li) for the case of continuos functions

Comment: As stated, $x_n \to x$ allows some $x_n=x$, so possibly zero denominator.  So you need a more careful statement.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you mean that I just consider $g(x)=\displaystyle\frac{f(x_n)-f(x)}{x_n-x}$, since for every sequence $\{x_n\}:\ x_n\to x$, we have $g(x_n)\to L$, this implies $L=g(x)$ ?

Comment: It’s unfortunate that the problem has $x$ fixed. We need $g(y)$ for $y\ne x$. And why is the limit the same $L$ for every sequence?

Comment: @TedShifrin $L$ is the same limit for every sequence because of the uniqueness of limit, I think

Comment: No, that completely begs the question.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have no idea how to show that

Comment: **HINT**: If you have two sequences, you can make a third sequence that incorporates them both.

Comment: @TedShifrin so by this way, I can show that $g(x_n)$ convergent to the same limit for any sequence $x_n\to x$ ?